# Create new test suite with Rspec or extend current Test::Unit setup?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, rspec, bdd

So I'm extending a friend's project and he's done all the development with TDD using Test::Unit

I use Rspec in all my projects and want to avoid having to learn a new tool. Is it bad practice to have 2 separate test suites, one in Test::Unit and one in Rspec?

I've also considered using Shoulda to extend Test::Unit to sort of feel like I'm using Rspec.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite difficult to know easily if your code is cover by test or not with both framework.

With Rspec you can use all Test::Unit stuff like assert_*